# Is the following iOS code safe? (__autoreleasing semantics)

Tags: ios, automatic-ref-counting, autorelease

```
-(NSData *)jsonRepresentation:(NSError **error)error {
   NSDictionary *dict = [self getDictRepresentation];
   return [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dict options:nil error:error];
}

// Some other place...

NSError *__autoreleasing error = nil;
NSData *json = [obj jsonRepresentation:&error];
```

Do autoreleasing semantics safely convey `error` up the stack to my second code block?

Comment: Those autoreleasing mechanics are actually implied for local variables (with a few exceptions) and do not need to be explicitly stated. But yes, it is correct.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII: What do you mean? Local variables of obj-c types default to `__strong` unless otherwise specified.

Comment: @KevinBallard I meant that they behave like an autoreleasing value whenever they may extend the lifetime of the block in which they are declared. Return values, in particular, become __autoreleasing (unless, of course you specify another return type attribute). In very few scenarios is __autoreleasing ever really needed.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII: I'm not sure what you're trying to say. Return values of methods aren't ownership-qualified at all. Instead they're considered either a "retained return value" or an "unretained return value", and in the latter case, ARC only guarantees that the object will survive across the call boundary. This may involve placing it in the autorelease pool, or it may not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's correct, but you should specify this modifier in the method declaration, and not in the declaration of the variable. Even the official documentation of Apple mentions this very situation explicitly:

> `__autoreleasing` is used to denote arguments that are passed by reference (`id *`) and are autoreleased on return.

Comment: It's good to note, however, that you are supposed to specify `__autoreleasing` on the method declaration itself, not the arguments to the method.

Answer (score 5):

As per [the clang ARC spec](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#indirect-parameters), a method argument of the form `NSError **` (or rather, a pointer to any obj-c object) is implicitly assumed to be `NSError * __autoreleasing *`. This means that the error will be autoreleased in the method.

As for the call site, if you call it with an `__autoreleasing` variable, as you have, then everything is just fine. In fact, I recommend this pattern. However, it will still work if you call it with a `__strong` variable instead. In that case, the compiler will generate an unnamed `__autoreleasing` temporary, pass the address of that to the method, and then upon return, it will assign the temporary into the `__strong`. So if you have

```
NSError *foo;
[bar callMethodWithError:&foo];
```

the compiler will treat this the same as

```
NSError *foo;
NSError * __autoreleasing tmp = foo;
[bar callMethodWithError:&tmp];
foo = tmp;
```

[It's actually slightly more complicated than that](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#passing-to-an-out-parameter-by-writeback) if the out-param is marked `out`, but this is generally how it works.